# Grails SOAP WS fails with handshake failure only in DEBUG mode (intellij)

Tags: ssl, intellij-idea, grails

I'm trying to run our Grails application in debug mode (through Intellij), but our SOAP WS fails with handshake failure. This does not happen when Grails is run with run-app. It also does not happen if I run the application with -debug-jvm and attach a remote debugger. I'm experiencing strange behavior when debugging using this method (application hangs, breakpoints get ignored, debugger variables and watches get stuck on collecting information forever), so I'm just looking to get it working "normally" and work from there.

I also get no extra output using -Djavax.net.debug=ssl, so I'm not sure why the handshake is failing.

My question would be how do I get the debug SSL output to figure out why the handshake is failing. Also posting this to see if anyone knows why this error might only happen when using Intellij's debug feature.